# Oil soaked lettuce leaf found on counter - food safety issue?

Tags: food-safety

I found a lettuce leaf that had been part of a very oily salad under a bowl and wet from dishwashing water. I think the oily lettuce has been there up to four days (someone else in household didn't clean up) and has been wet under the bowl probably up to 22 hours. Is that considered anaerobic (botulism-y)? Or is it okay because it's not completely in oil (but under a bowl)? I put it and paper towels I cleaned it up with in two bags in garbage using gloves. I would like to not be so worried about greasy dishes and oily salad leaves but don't know if I should be bleaching the counter and my gloves.

Answer (score 4):

I think you over did it (2 bags and gloves!!).

Just pick it up, throw it and clean with your regular cleaning routines.